# How to use LISTAGG redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

SELECT Distinct 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS deleted.' || LISTAGG("table_name",',') || ';' FROM svv_all_columns WHERE schema_name = 'sn' and database_name='db';

ERROR:One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created tables. Examples of user table only functions are LISTAGG, MEDIAN, PERCENTILE_CONT, et

SELECT Distinct 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS deleted.' || LISTAGG("table_name",',') || ';' FROM svv_all_columns WHERE schema_name = 'sn' and database_name='db';

It concatanetes all table names in one drop statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what LISTAGG() does - it aggregates strings from multiple rows together.  It can work in conjunction with GROUP BY to combine strings from only within a group.

It sounds like you just want to have individual table names concatenated with the static text.  Like this:

```
SELECT Distinct 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS deleted.' || "table_name" || ';' FROM svv_all_columns WHERE schema_name = 'sn' and database_name='db'
```

Which will put each DROP statement on its own row.  If instead you want one block of text you can use LISTAGG() over the combined strings like this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS deleted.' || "table_name" || ';',',') FROM svv_all_columns WHERE schema_name = 'sn' and database_name='db';
```

Now DISTINCT doesn't make sense in this case as there is only one string.  This could result in extra DROP statement so if you really need the minimum number of DROP statements AND for all of this to be in 1 string:

```
WITH drops AS (
  SELECT Distinct 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS deleted.' || "table_name" || ';' AS statement
  FROM svv_all_columns WHERE schema_name = 'sn' and database_name='db'
)
SELECT LISTAGG(statement,' ') 
FROM drops;
```

Note that I took the ',' out as the text separator as this doesn't make sense in a block of SQL.

Hopefully these examples will give you enough info to understand the basics of LISTAGG().